# How to extract the value of the src attribute using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I have problems with something I don't even know the name.

I'm trying to reach the link next to where it says `src= "LINK"`  with selenium.

I have `class name = tWeCI`, I guess I need to achieve using this but I have no idea how to do it.

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/CYMHMEGBSRT/")
a = browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="tWeCl")
```

Output:

```
https://instagram.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/271301182_1082110899295465_6686845989868801609_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5jbGlwcy5iYXNlbGluZSIsInFlX2dyb3VwcyI6IltcImlnX3dlYl9kZWxpdmVyeV92dHNfb3RmXCJdIn0&_nc_ht=instagram.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=6RJahYZ39DIAX_ul9E4&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&vs=453007466354843_3354420889&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdENjZLeERwbE1LVExOZ0RBRWtPNE5YLWNzeGNicV9FQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHS0ZaS1JCMldIUXZxRzhCQUJ4bFB2ZnVrbE1hYnFfRUFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwAVAAAmqN%2FFrpms4z8VAigCQzMsF0A%2BmZmZmZmaGBJkYXNoX2Jhc2VsaW5lXzFfdjERAHX%2BBwA%3D&_nc_rid=c8bb85b1e6&ccb=7-4&oe=62408107&oh=00_AT-E77LrFH7G6VVXGeh8bRFQsu95hhQlqUGZdinzFBIUYQ&_nc_sid=83d603"
```

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image: pic1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the value of the *src* attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CYMHMEGBSRT/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "video.tWeCl"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CYMHMEGBSRT/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//video[@class='tWeCl']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://instagram.fpnq13-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/271301182_1082110899295465_6686845989868801609_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5jbGlwcy5iYXNlbGluZSIsInFlX2dyb3VwcyI6IltcImlnX3dlYl9kZWxpdmVyeV92dHNfb3RmXCJdIn0&_nc_ht=instagram.fpnq13-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=6RJahYZ39DIAX-Iphu9&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&vs=453007466354843_3354420889&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdENjZLeERwbE1LVExOZ0RBRWtPNE5YLWNzeGNicV9FQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHS0ZaS1JCMldIUXZxRzhCQUJ4bFB2ZnVrbE1hYnFfRUFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwAVAAAmqN%2FFrpms4z8VAigCQzMsF0A%2BmZmZmZmaGBJkYXNoX2Jhc2VsaW5lXzFfdjERAHX%2BBwA%3D&_nc_rid=34a08d5a01&ccb=7-4&oe=62408107&oh=00_AT9sh_BH__zjeReDB7lde4t3avzYqDjimTJRnoZi6Lj-TQ&_nc_sid=83d603
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```